# Clicking on the button crashes the application with unhandeled exception

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am getting following error.....

tacktrace:

at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at F2S.UI.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/ravichandra/Desktop/19-10-2012/F2S/F2S.UI/Main.cs:21
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)

Native stacktrace:

```
0   navigation                          0x00090dfc mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
1   navigation                          0x00005c28 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9ca8259b _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   UIKit                               0x0223555a -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
5   UIKit                               0x022dab76 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
6   UIKit                               0x022db03f -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 503
7   UIKit                               0x022da2fe -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 549
8   UIKit                               0x0225aa30 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 513
9   UIKit                               0x0225ac56 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
10  UIKit                               0x02241384 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 464
11  UIKit                               0x02234aa9 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 8196
12  GraphicsServices                    0x047f6fa9 PurpleEventCallback + 1274
13  CoreFoundation                      0x0119c1c5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
14  CoreFoundation                      0x01101022 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
15  CoreFoundation                      0x010ff90a __CFRunLoopRun + 2218
16  CoreFoundation                      0x010fedb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
17  CoreFoundation                      0x010feccb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
18  GraphicsServices                    0x047f5879 GSEventRunModal + 207
19  GraphicsServices                    0x047f593e GSEventRun + 114
20  UIKit                               0x02232a9b UIApplicationMain + 1175
21  ???                                 0x0d90a384 0x0 + 227582852
22  ???                                 0x0d909180 0x0 + 227578240
23  ???                                 0x0d9089a0 0x0 + 227576224
24  ???                                 0x0d908a2f 0x0 + 227576367
25  navigation                          0x00009fe2 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
26  navigation                          0x0016b87e mono_runtime_invoke + 126
27  navigation                          0x0016fa04 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
28  navigation                          0x00174df5 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
29  navigation                          0x000671e5 mono_jit_exec + 149
30  navigation                          0x00203e41 main + 2209
31  navigation                          0x00002fe5 start + 53
32  ???                                 0x00000005 0x0 + 5
```

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries.

=================================================================

please anyone help me

Here is my code

```
        btnMylocation.Clicked += (sender, e) => 
        {
            imgbg.Hidden=false;
            lbltime.Hidden=false;
            btnup.Hidden=false;
            btndown.Hidden=false;
            imghazard.Hidden=false;
            lblfeets.Hidden=false;


            try
            {
                if(!Reachability.IsHostReachable ("www.google.com"))
                {

                    alertview.NetworkFail ();

                }

                else
                {

                this.mysegments.SelectedSegment = 0;

                mapView.RemoveAnnotations (mapView.Annotations);

                var locationservice = new LocationService ();
                var currentLocation = locationservice.GetCurrentLocation ();
                var visregion = BuildVisibleRegion (currentLocation);

                mapView.SetRegion (visregion, true);
                targetimage.Hidden = true;

                locations = LocationManager.Locations ();

                List<double> distlist=new List<double>();

                foreach(LocationModel d in locations)
                {

                    var dist=distance (currentLocation.Latitude,currentLocation.Longitude,Convert.ToDouble (d.latitude),Convert.ToDouble (d.longitude));
                    distlist.Add (dist);

                }
                if(distlist.Count!=0)
                {

                    distlist.Sort ();
                    double min= distlist[0];

                foreach (LocationModel f in locations)
                {

                    string feets = (min*3280).ToString ();

                    var dist=distance (currentLocation.Latitude,currentLocation.Longitude,Convert.ToDouble (f.latitude),Convert.ToDouble (f.longitude));

                    if(min == dist)
                    {
                        string lat = f.latitude;
                        string lon = f.longitude;
                        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString (f.hazardid,"hazardid");  

                        this.View.AddSubview (imgbg);
                        this.View.AddSubview (imghazard);
                        this.View.AddSubview (lblfeets);
                        this.View.AddSubview (btnup);
                        this.View.AddSubview (btndown); 
                        this.View.AddSubview (lbltime);

                    if (f.hazardtype == 1) 
                    {   

                        pins.Clear ();
                        pins.Add (new PoliceAnnotation (new CLLocationCoordinate2D (Convert.ToDouble (lat), Convert.ToDouble (lon)), "Click here to Report",""));
                        mapView.AddAnnotationObject (pins [0]);
                        mapView.AddAnnotation (mapAnnotations [(int)Anotationindex.police]);

                        lblfeets.Text=feets  + " fts";
                        lbltime.Text=f.ReportDate + " Ago";
                        imghazard.Image=UIImage.FromFile ("Images/police-cop-mark.png");

                    } 

                    else if (f.hazardtype == 2) 
                    {

                        duipins.Clear ();
                        duipins.Add (new DuiAnnotation (new CLLocationCoordinate2D (Convert.ToDouble (lat), Convert.ToDouble (lon)), "Click here to Report",""));
                        mapView.AddAnnotationObject (duipins [0]);
                        mapView.AddAnnotation (mapAnnotations [(int)Anotationindex.dui]);


                        lblfeets.Text=feets  + " fts";
                        lbltime.Text=f.ReportDate + " Ago";
                        imghazard.Image=UIImage.FromFile ("Images/dui-stop-mark.png");      

                    }
                    else if(f.hazardtype==3)
                    {

                        campins.Clear ();
                        campins.Add (new SpeedcamAnnotation (new CLLocationCoordinate2D (Convert.ToDouble (lat), Convert.ToDouble (lon)), "",""));
                        mapView.AddAnnotationObject (campins [0]);
                        mapView.AddAnnotation (mapAnnotations [(int)Anotationindex.cam]);


                        lblfeets.Text=feets  + " fts";
                        lbltime.Text=f.ReportDate + " Ago";
                        imghazard.Image=UIImage.FromFile ("Images/speed-camera-mark.png");

                    }

                    }

                    }

                    btnup.TouchUpInside += (sender1, e1) =>
                    {

                    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString("1","Status");
                    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Init();
                    Response = LocationManager.ConfirmLocation();

                    if(Response.Status == "1" || Response.Status == "12")
                    {
                        UIAlertView alert1 = new UIAlertView ("Success","",null,"Ok");  
                        alert1.Show ();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

                    };

                    btndown.TouchUpInside += (sender1, e1) => 
                    {

                    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString("0","Status");
                    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Init();
                    Response = LocationManager.ConfirmLocation ();

                    if(Response.Status == "1" || Response.Status == "12")
                    {
                        UIAlertView alert1 = new UIAlertView ("Success","",null,"Ok");  
                        alert1.Show ();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

                    };

                   }

                }

               }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

                if(ex.Message == "Network Fail")

                    alertview.NetworkFail ();

                else

                    alertview.ProcessFailed ();

                }

            };
```

Clicking first time  on btnMylocation shows a popup with two buttons and clicking on two buttons working fine , but when i am trying to click on btnMylocation again its opening the popup but clicking any one of two buttons btnup and btndown crashes the application.......any idea please....

Comment: It looks like the GC freed the button because nobody kept a reference to it. Can you show your code so we can be sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolf is right, there is a way to make this crash happen by setting up events improperly.  It is the way the GC interacts with Objective-C in MonoTouch.

So for example if you put this in `ViewDidLoad` on an outlet named `myButton`, it will work fine:

```
myButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
{
  //Do something
};
```

But if you did this:

```
myButton1.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
{
  var myButton2 = new UIButton();
  myButton2.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
  {
    //Do something
  };  
  //Add button2 to the view, etc.
};
```

Then `myButton2` will click properly perhaps the first time, but eventually you will get a crash after the GC collects.  This happens because the C# wrapper for `myButton2` will get garbarge collected, but the Objective-C instance will still hang around.  When the Objective-C instance get's a click, it's can't call into C# because it is gone.

An easy way to work around it to so make the button a member variable of your class:

`private UIButton myButton;`

Just make sure not to create it over and over.

Comment: I agree with the workaround - but the crash in the case you've illustrated is an MT bug, isn't it? I don't think myButton2 should get garbage collected in this case, should it? (Just checking I understand!)

Comment: Not really a bug, but a limitation.  I'm not sure what they could do to fix it.  The way it works right now, if a C# wrapper object is disposed/GC'd, it will free up it's respective Objective-C object if it's reference count is zero--this is how memory management works in Objective-C.  But the reference count is not zero in this case, because it's still on screen and in a collection of subviews.